# Facebook Like Box isn't working

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to add a Facebook "Like Box" to an existing website, as [**described here**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box)

The Page I'm promoting works just fine in preview-box on that page.

But when I copy/paste the code as shown to my website, it instead shows a fraction of an empty facebook page with only a partially visible error message.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?profile_id=SenRandyGordon&amp;width=260&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true"
        scrolling="no" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowTransparency="true" 
        style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:260px; height:px"></iframe>
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I added "Like Box"'s in the past, before Facebook released their new API.

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
You have to replace all the "&amp;" of the Facebook Likebox generator code with "&" - then it works.
```

Combine this method with Lemmy's method to make it work.

So the final result looks like these instead

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?profile=1&id=SenRandyGordon&width=260&connections=10&stream=true&header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:260px; height:px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted the code supplied for the iframe, and it didn't work. I discovered there was no http: before the code. Once I put it there, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `profile_id=SenRandyGordon` to `profile=1&id=SenRandyGordon` 
It work for me

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  Tried that, but it still doesn't work for me.  I'm beginning to suspect something else in my setup is interfering with the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I  also faced same problem using facebook's social plugin.
In this plugin if user enter wrong input then security question comes with random generated code with 2 words, but user can view only 1 word means it shows partial part..

Here is Onther solution .... It Really Works!!!

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US'> 
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>FB.init('aaafdced248eed501f09f66e3c5b7de9');</script>
<fb:fan profile_id=\"118774364811981\" stream=\"0\" connections=\"10\" logobar=\"0\" width=\"244\" height=\"240\" css='serverside_facebook.css?1'> 
</fb:fan>
```

I used above code in Java  `verticalPanel.getElement().setInnerHTML("above code");`

It really works!

Comment: Any facebook code that uses `FeatureLoader.js.php` is **deprecated**, as per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/ . What this means is, you should not use `FeatureLoader.js.php` in any new code.

Answer (score 0):

try thins iframe code working fine and tested by me on wordpress

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FEnter_Your_FB_ID_OR_USERNAME&amp;width&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

John's answer might work. Haven't tried it. This worked for me:
change `profile_id=` to just `id=` in the embed code.